# How to get all the columns in descending order in a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How do I obtain a dataframe in a descending order?
I just want all the columns in descending order.
I have tried doing the following:

```
for i in loadings.columns: 
    descending_order = loadings.sort_values(i,ascending=False)

    print(descending_order)
```

But this does not give me a required dataframe. After each iteration, I have to look for individual column see it in a descending order.

I am sure there is simple solution, I am just not thinking clearly.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72909546/sort-dataframe-on-multiple-columns-not-working/72909889#72909889) answer - not upvoted, so cannot close like dupe.

Comment: Pandas assumes you want each row to stay intact and just changes the order of the rows.  Are you saying you don't care about the rows?  You want each column sorted on its own?

Comment: Ah. That's right. I didn't think about ROWS. I am so stupid. 
Alright, I will close this question.  Thanks for this.